# How do I make a secure GET request?

Tags: http, get

I’m just starting to learn how HTTP works, so I apologize if this question is a bit stupid.

Let’s say I want to get my friends list or some other private information from a web server. Since I’m only retrieving information, I would use a GET request, but this is private information, so I should send some form of authentication. Since the information in a GET request is stored in the URL, how do I keep my credentials secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST to hide private information.

Comment: Isn’t POST only for creating resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a private information such as ID or something else, i recommend you to use POST instead GET and use SSL for your apps. Or if you still want to use GET, you can encrypt it using base64 or something and combine it with unique ID when encrypt it

Comment: Aren’t you not supposed to use POST for retrieving information?